# Don't understand this TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects exception

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror, quotes

I get the error:
`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`
while running the code below. It involves that the year, month, and days be integers, and there is quotes within the quotes. My version of Python is 2.7 and because I am working on a work computer without admin privileges I can't update Python.

```
import os

#input1 is the first date, input2 is the second date, with a 1 day
difference
yearinput1 = input("What's the start year?")
monthinput1 = input("What's the start month?")
dayinput1 = input("What's the start day?")
yearinput2 = input("What's the end year?")
monthinput2 = input("What's the end month?")
dayinput2 = input("What's the end day?")

print"sudo mam-list-usagerecords -s \" ", yearinput1, "-" , monthinput1, "-", dayinput1, " \" -e \" ", yearinput2, "-" + monthinput2, "-", dayinput2, " \" --format csv --full"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take a time and read an article about string-formatting in python. E.g this [tutorial](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting) will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In your print statement, you have this:

```
"-" + monthinput2
```

`monthinput2` is an int while `"-"` is a string. You can convert `monthinput2` to a string:

```
"-" + str(monthinput2)
```